# SQLite connection issues

Tags: sqlite, devart, dotconnect

I am experiencing the strangest behavior when trying to test a project on a machine other than my development machine.  Everything works fine on the development machine, but when deploying the program, I receive "Error on opening DbConnection." with the InnerException "Unable to open database file."

Basically, I have an empty database (the schema only) in the same folder as the exe file, and like I said, everything works fine on the development machine.  I am using LinqConnect to query the SQLite database.  Here is the method that is having the error (also receive the same error with any methods that are accessing the database).

```
private void LoadAccountsFromDatabase()
{
    var accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();
    var connectionString =
        string.Format("Data Source='{0}';Version=3;Default Command Timeout=10000;", UserPreferences.DatabasePath);
    AccountsGrid.CommitEdit();
    AccountsGrid.SelectedItem = null;

    MessageBox.Show(connectionString);
    try
    {
        using (var db = new MainDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("step 4.5");
            var query = from a in db.Accounts
                where a.Inactive == 0 || a.Inactive == null || ShowInactiveCheckBox.IsChecked == true
                orderby a.AccountName, a.AccountNickname
                select a;

            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("step 4.6");
                if (query.Any())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("step 4.61");
                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("step 4.65");
                        accounts.Add(item);
                    }                            
                }

                MessageBox.Show("step 4.7");
                AccountsGrid.ItemsSource = accounts;
                MessageBox.Show("step 4.8");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("accounts add " + e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("load accounts " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

I get the "step 4.6" message, and then the exception. I don't see "step 4.61" so it appears that the error is on the line `if (query.Any())` which is what is bizarre, as the underlying tables are empty, so there are no results.  Does anyone have any ideas what could be the issue here?  I do have the LinqConnect DLL files deploying with the exe, as well as the sqlite3.dll, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that I was missing the sqlite3.dll in the correct output folder on the deployment machine.  I could have sworn that it was there, but when I copied the entire project to another machine to test it, I was still getting the error, and when I looked in the `bin` directory, that DLL was missing.  Oops!